# How to delete a sub record based on criteria in Cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.1

I have 2 tables "Topic" and "Post" linked in the model by hasMany

I want to delete the Post entry with id = 3 since it doesn't have a message.

In the model for table "Post", I have this "beforeSave" :

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {

  if ($this->data['Post']['message'] == '') {
    CODE TO DELETE HERE
  }
}
```

This is my $this->request->data :

```
Array
(
[Topic] => Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [topic_title] => This is my topic
)

[Post] => Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Blah
            [message] => My message
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Second Blah
            [message] => Second My message
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => Second Blah
            [message] => 
        )
    )
)
```

I can't figure out how to delete in the model or is this the wrong approach ?

I've now also tried this in the controller before saveAssociated :

```
$this->loadmodel('Post');

foreach ($this->request->data['Post'] as $i => $post) {

 if ($post['message'] == '') {
     unset($this->request->data['Post'][$i]);

     $options = array( 'conditions' => array( 'Post.id' => $i) );
     $this->Post->find('first', $options);

     if ($this->Post->delete()) {
      echo "Post id : " . $i . ' - Deleted';
    } else {
      echo "Post id : " . $i . ' - Not deleted';
    }
 }
```

}

This gives me "Post id xxx Deleted" however the Post record isn't deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm using "saveAssociated" I also have to "unset" the post in "$this->request->data" otherwise it will be saved again.

```
$this->loadmodel('Post');

foreach ($this->request->data['Post'] as $i => $post) {

 if ($post['message'] == '') {
   unset($this->request->data['Post'][$i]);

 if ($this->Post->delete($post['id'], false)) {
  echo "Post id : " . $i . ' - Deleted';
 } else {
  echo "Post id : " . $i . ' - Not deleted';
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unset the data in your `beforeSave` if the message is empty like this:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {

    foreach ($this->data['Post'] as $i => $post) {
        if ($post['message'] == '') {
            unset($this-data['Post'][$i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply however I'm afraid that doesn't work.

 [code] if ($this->data['Post']['message'] == '') {
    unset($this->data['Post']);
  }

Comment: I can't edit my last comment so I have to add here. I don't understand the code you wrote for the Post model since I shouldn't have to go through each Post in the model. It's getting called anyway for each Post.

Comment: It isn't going through each post in the model.  `$this->data` in `beforeSave` represents the data that is about to be saved.  So the idea here is that you will remove posts with empty messages before you save them.  A better idea would probably be to just add some model validation requiring the message field to not be empty. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html

Comment: I showed it in this way since it's easier to understand. On the form their is actually a little of javascript action going on therefore I need to delete the post in the model or the controller. 

However your code does not work in the Post model. "I get Illegal string offset 'message'"